# Android camera feature: Augmented reality

Tags: android, camera, geolocation, compass-geolocation

Hi I want to develop an Android application that must have a feature that I don't even know what is his name but I want to know and know if there is an Android API that do that or I have to develop it by myself.

**The feature**

I know the geolocalization of an object and I want the users can turn on his camera and point to certain points and show the location of that object in a previous determinate meters. An application that do something similar is this:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flightradar24pro

And as a picture is worth a thousand words (Image by Flightradar24):

[image: Image by **Flightradar24**]

**PostData:** I don't know if this is the place to ask this question if not please let me know in a comment and I will delete it. Thank you.

Comment: It's basically an "augmented reality" technique. You're not likely to find the exact code you're looking for ready-to-go, and it's a fairly complex field.

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to check if [**Urbo SDK**](https://github.com/Fringefy/Urbo) can get the things done for you.