# Augmented Reality With Android: Recognize and Track Augmented Images (ARCore with TensorFlow and MLkit)

Tags: android, tensorflow, augmented-reality, arcore, google-mlkit

I am trying to do the following:

**Tracking augmented image with android device and load text info** (it would be better if I can load text views) to show information besides trackable image, something like this:

[Android camera feature: Augmented reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246315/android-camera-feature-augmented-reality)

In addition to put Model to highlight the trackable image, Since now I could not decide from where to begin.
I have checked this maintained library for tracking and loading 3D objects (Which is maintained version for Scene Form Google):

**After searching with these techniques, I found that:**

- **ARCore** For tracking
- **Scene view** is a  replacement of **OpenGl** to load 3D objects in a simpler way.
- **ML Kit** for better detection of objects in images that I am going to track, if it is being used with Tensor Flow, you can develop Custom Models.

**I found the solutions**

- Combine Scene View with ML Kit and Tensor Flow.
- Use ML kit in order to track and detect but without placing 3d objects since this might have performance issues.

  [ML Kit Vision Showcase App with Material Design](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/material-showcase)

**but I have doubts...**

- The Question is: Can I use ML Kit, Tensor Flow and
  SceneView/SceneForm instead of OpenGl for simpler coding,  or using
  ML Kit with Arcore and OpenGl is better since AR Core Library
  Google already have samples included using machine learning techniques.
  Or using augmented image (AR Core Augmented Image) can achieve the
  same purpose.
- Is there a better way to achieve this purpose more than the solution I presented above.
- Can track multiple objects with placing 3D model cause a high consumable task for battery and a lower performance.
- Why AR Core present an example wit ML Kit, if ML Kit alone can track and detect multiple objects in real time.

[ML KIT Image Labeling](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/custom-models)

[AR Core](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/machine-learning)

[Scene View](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/machine-learning)